# Writing hard coded data in populate file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

In my lib/tasks/populate.rake file I have to write some hard coded data in proper html format with proper alignment. How can I write it in the populate file? Is there any way to parse the HTML tags after writing?For random data I know there is populator gem. But I want some hard coded data. Please some help me out.

Answer (score 0):

First write html data inside html file then align and validate file. If everything is write then copy html data inside file to `lib/tasks/populate.rake` file. There are many online tools that can do validation. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: 1. Payment Mode:
                                  Direct Payment or Telegraphic Transfer to:
                                    A/c Name:  xyz Technologies Pvt. Ltd.
                                    A/c No.:   4343431
                                    A/c Type:  Current Account 
                                    Bank & Branch: xyz Bank Ltd., 
                                    RTGS/NEFT IFSC Code: dfdgf
                                    SWIFT Code: ICdfg
                                2. PAN No.: Adgf
                                3. Ser. Tax. Code No.: AABCI2464GST001

Comment: This is my data. How can I align it properly?

Comment: make use of html table to align data properly

Comment: Actually I mean to say that can I wite html tags in populate.rake file

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Ruby heredoc](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/4438542511/heredoc-and-indent) syntax to align your code

```
text = <<END
<p>Whatever you want to write in whatever form</p>
               line with spaces in front
        Another indented line
Account No. : XYZ
END

text = text.html_safe
```

There should be no spaces before the closing `END`.

Comment: Can I write it in populate.rake file?

Comment: I wrote this in my populate file:

Comment: company.company_notes = <<END
                                1. Payment Mode:
                                  Direct Payment or Telegraphic Transfer to:
                                    A/c Name:  xyz. Ltd.
                                    Bank & Branch: abc.
                                    RTGS/NEFT IFSC Code: Ityth56
                                    SWIFT Code: I6545
                                2. PAN No.: Ahgfgj
                 
                                END
       company.company_notes = company_notes.html_safe

Comment: When I do rake db:drop I get this error: rake aborted!
/home/icicle/work/code/invoiced/lib/tasks/populate.rake:274: can't find string "END" anywhere before EOF
/home/icicle/work/code/invoiced/lib/tasks/populate.rake:104: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END